# Call a service class Once in a day when application is Starts in android ,with less Battery Consumption

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I want to call a Service Class, when User Starts the Application Once in a Day in Android.

Manifest Code:

```
<service android:name=".DailyRemainder" >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Java Code:

```
 // for Repeating Process
    Intent myIntent = new     Intent(sign_in.this,.DailyRemainder.class);
    pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getService(sign_in.this, 0,myIntent, 0);
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
     calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20); alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent1);
```

Above code is running in **background drains my Mobile Battery**,
but i need when user starts the **Application that time Service Should Run Once** in a Day. How to Achieve this.

Comment: you can use job scheduler in android, there comes a lot of configuration with it. You can configure it according to your requirement.

Comment: make it clear. you want your service starts when you open your application? you would not start service at the time when your application closed. you can save time stamp of last start of your service in share preferences and check is day over when you launch your application. is it your case?

Comment: Job Scheduler is not available on APIs <21.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer for my Question using Shared pref.

When Activity is Starting ,First time in a day Async task will run. then inside on Post execute todays date is saved.

after that async will not execute in a same day. **I removed Alarm Manager part**

```
// Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences settingsShrepref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "MyPrefFileShred";

    // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_TODAY_DATE_ANDTIME = "TimeToday";
```

**Inside Oncreate Activity**

```
    /* Added Servcie count Once in a day Fetch from Server*/

            try {

                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                Date date = new Date();
                 TodayDate_String = dateFormat.format(date);


                settingsShrepref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);
                editor = settingsShrepref.edit();

                String Val=settingsShrepref.getString(KEY_TODAY_DATE_ANDTIME,"");


                Log.i("Stored Val", Val);
                Log.i("Today date", TodayDate_String);
                if(!Val.equals(TodayDate_String))
                {

                    //for  SYNC web to Local
                    try
                    {
                        Log.d("Comments", "FirstTime Started");

                        // get Internet status
                        isInternetPresent = cd1.isConnectingToInternet();

                        // check for Internet status
                        if (isInternetPresent)
                        {
                            new AsyncCallWSCategoryCOUNTFetch().execute();

                        }
                        else {

                            Log.i("CATEGORY COUNT ", "Not Internet ......!");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i(" CATEGORY COUNT ", "EXCEPTION in reading Data from Web Async task ONstart ......!");

                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("Comments", "Second TIme");

                    Getmethod();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("", "Exception here Run Service.");
            }
```

**Inside Async task On post Execute**

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            Log.i(TAG_CategoryCOUNT, "onPostExecute");


            try {



                //the app is being launched for first time in a Day, do something
                Log.d("Comments", "First Time");

                // Storing name in pref
                editor.putString(KEY_TODAY_DATE_ANDTIME, TodayDate_String);
                // commit changes
                editor.commit();

                String Val=settingsShrepref.getString(KEY_TODAY_DATE_ANDTIME, null);
                Log.d("after Insertion data Date", Val);



            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 7):

the `AlarmManager` is only the feature that can wakeup your device 100%.

Any service doesn't consume your battery at all if it doesn't do any work. I think you have to read your code more carefully.

Nevertheless, some advice.
You can call broadcast receiver instead of Service to wake up.
That is, use

```
Intent intent = new Intent("yourBroadCastString");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...);
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            am.setExact(wakeup?AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP:AlarmManager.RTC, nexttime, pi);
        } else{
            am.set(wakeup?AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP:AlarmManager.RTC, nexttime, pi);
        }
```

in the case above `am.setExact` can really consume the battery,

to wakeup your device in this case you have to use inside broadcast:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                    PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                    PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, _.APPNAME + Integer.toString(index));
        if (wakeLock != null && wakeLock.isHeld()){
            wakeLock.acquire();
        }

ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(ctx.getPackageName(),
                yourServiceClass.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(ctx, intent.setComponent(comp));
```

inside `androidmanifest.xml`

```
<receiver android:name="yourBroadCast">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="yourBroadCastString"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And your code is really bad:

Omg, what the hell is this?
`Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
long t = calendar.getTimeInMillis();`
I think you have to read your code.

Comment: i given for that after 20 secs start the service

Comment: how can i run once in a day when app is started?

Comment: Due to restrictions of the new API only JobSchedule is allowed. That's sad but true.

Answer (score -1):

Use [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) if you also want to keep the device awake or wakeup the device for the service.

For running it once a day when the app is started is easy to do, just use SharedPreferences to store when the task is done, so that when the user opens up the task again a simple check in SharedPrefs should prevent the same task from being run again.